# Should I Down-Vote Questions That Have Invalid Facts?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a lot of questions on here that ask something like, *why is blank important because the way I see it...* and then they go on to list a string of facts that aren't true, and there question has a lot of down-votes. Should we DV people just because their ill-educated in one part of music? Isn't the reason they're here to learn, to grow from their mistakes? Why are we down-voting people just because they haven't learned everything about music yet? I know I've asked a few questions like this, but it didn't get down-voted...

Answer (score 3):

If there are "facts" that are the basis for the question itself, then perhaps the question makes no sense if those assumptions are actually false. I could see those attracting downvotes. A much better approach, though, is to leave a comment explaining the mistake and asking for the question to be edited and improved.

That said, without some examples, it's very tricky to know what you mean - your assumption that people are down voting because of this is not necessarily true. Unless the downvoter commented that that was the reason, then you are just guessing.

Comment: I just found a recent example here, http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/48873/why-is-it-called-dominant-function-and-not-subtonic-function There's a downvote for a good question; is just that the OP was mislead

Comment: It doesn't matter, and you cannot know anyone's reason for downvotes unless they decide to tell you. This is a deliberate feature. Personally I don't see that one as a good question - it has a few issues - and sober people will feel more strongly than me.

Comment: It also is not an example of the question you have asked about, as far as I can tell. Does it have false assumptions in it?

Comment: @not so much as false assumptions, but more like the example question in my question, just worded a bit different like: why isn't blank called blank, because the way I see it...